# Can a reference to an lvalue subroutine be used as an lvalue?

Tags: perl, subroutine, lvalue

I'm having trouble using a Perl subroutine reference as an lvalue. Am I doing something wrong here, or is it not possible to do this? I'm using ActiveState Perl 5.20 on Windows.

```perl
package Warning {
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Carp 'carp';
  sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    return bless [@_], $class;
  }
  sub initbyname {
    my $self = shift;
    $self = $self->new unless ref $self;
    carp "'Warning' object already initialized" if @$self;
    while (@_) {
      my $method = shift;
      my $value = shift;
      my $sub = $self->can($method);
      $sub ? ( $sub->() = $value ) : 
          ( carp "method '$method' not found" );
     }
     return $self;
  }
  sub biff :lvalue { $_[0]->[ 0] }
  sub boff :lvalue { $_[0]->[ 1] }
}

package ThisWorks {
  use strict;
  use warnings;
  use Carp 'carp';
  sub new { 
    my $class = shift;
    return bless [@_], $class;
  }
  sub initbyname {
    my $self = shift;
    $self = $self->new unless ref $self;
    carp "'ThisWorks' object already initialized" if @$self;
    while (@_) {
      my $method = shift;
      my $value = shift;
      $self->can($method) ? ( $self->$method = $value ) :
          ( carp "method '$method' not found" );
     }
     return $self;
  }
  sub riff :lvalue { $_[0]->[ 0] }
  sub roff :lvalue { $_[0]->[ 1] }
}

package main;
use v5.20;
use strict;
use warnings;
my $warning   = Warning->initbyname( boff => 12 );
my $thisworks = ThisWorks->initbyname( roff => 13 );
say "warning->boff = ", $warning->boff // "uninitialized!";
say "thisworks->roff = ", $thisworks->roff;
```

Prints:

```
Useless assignment to a temporary at a.pl line 17.
warning->boff = uninitialized!
thisworks->roff = 13
```

Comment: Formatting answer: add 4 spaces from upper line

Comment: Thanks. Odd behavior, but I guess everyone else in the world somehow knows this. Oops, when I tried it, I was told that it was "code" and that I couldn't post.

Comment: This is markdown, not only SO but reddit, gitlab, slack, github and so on...

Comment: OK, I guess it's known to professional programmers these days. I retired over a decade ago.

Comment: There is a help link when you post which tells you all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `boff` assigns to `$_[0]->[1]`, but you are calling `boff` without any argument.

```perl
$sub->()
```

is supposed to be

```perl
$sub->( $self )
```

Comment: Doh! $self->method() is really just method($self), but the latter syntax is used when calling a method using a reference. Odd that I didn't find that with a search. Thanks.

Comment: Now I'm wondering why I didn't get an exception in the method when attempting to dereference $_[0].

Comment: Re "*`$self->method()` is really just `method($self)`*", Except for inheritance. So it's really, `$self->can("method")->($self)` (since `can` also obeys inheritance), which brings us to the answer.

Comment: Re "*why I didn't get an exception*", autovivification. Dereferencing an `undef` variable in lvalue context generates the variable the dereference requires. So `$_[0]->[1]` is equivalent to `( $_[0] //= [] )->[1]` here.